# SSH: use specific key when logging in

Tags: ssh

In `/home/petri/.ssh/` I have my private key called `petri`. When I try to connect to my server using ssh, it does not accept my private key. Running `-v` learns that it is not trying my key `petry`, but just the non-existent id_rsa and id_dsa:

```
$ssh server
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: petri@office
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: petri@office
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: petri@office
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: petri@office
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/petri/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/petri/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The odd thing is that things were fine before. Anyway, how do I tell SSH to use my `petri` key and quite trying the non-existent standard keys?

NOTE: my .ssh folder is chmod `700` and the petri file is `600`, that is not the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Specify the key in your ssh command, something like "ssh -i ~/.ssh/petri server.example.com"
2. Create a .ssh/config file with something like:

> Host *
>
> IdentityFile /home/petri/.ssh/petri

For more options, do a "man ssh_config" or "man ssh", depending on which you want to do.

Comment: 3. Rename the private key to something standard and save yourself lots of trouble.

Comment: Yes, I would do the rename if that's the only key you're using.  If you use multiple keys, use a bunch of Host entries in ~/.ssh/config.  If it's a one-off connection, use the "-i" option for the ssh command.

Comment: @Alex Holst: I have also other keys to install and prefer to differentiate them with easy names.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you have multiple private keys on one system? I have one at home and one at work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ssh -i /path/to/petri
```